# extract data from numpy array of shape ()

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `()` which for all intents and purposes is a scalar. If it contains a floating point number, I can simply `float(arr)` to get a `float` back. (That isn't ideal because of the implicit conversion though.)

How to extract the data if it's a more complicated (`object`) data type? E.g.:

```py
import numpy
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol("x")
val = numpy.array(2 * x)

print(val, val.shape, val.dtype)
```

```
2*x () object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val.item()` or `val[()]` should work.